# How do you remove the beginning comma from a 2d array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Okay I realize their is no such thing as a 2d array in javascript, but arrays can contain arrays, so its like a 2d array.  Anyway I have a 2d array and it spits out a comma in the new line.  I was wondering how do you remove it?

Here is my HTML

```
<form>
    <h1>Please enter data</h1>
    <input id="names" type="text" placeholder="Name" />
    <input id="zipcodes" type="text" placeholder="Zip code" />
    <input type="button" value="Save" onclick="insertData()" /> <br />
    <input type="button" value="Display" onclick="displayData()" />
</form>

<div id="display"></div>
```

And my JavaScript

```
var namePlusZip = [[]];
var nameInput = document.getElementById("names");
var zipInput = document.getElementById("zipcodes");

var displayBox = document.getElementById("display");

function insertData() {
    namePlusZip.push([nameInput.value, zipInput.value]);
    delete namePlusZip[0];
    nameInput.value = "";
    zipInput.value = "";
}

function displayData(){
    displayBox.innerHTML = "";

    for (var i=0, l=namePlusZip.length; i<l; i++){
       if (namePlusZip[i] instanceof Array){
           namePlusZip[i] = namePlusZip[i].join(", ") + "</br>"; 
       }
    }

    displayBox.innerHTML += "Names and zip codes: " + namePlusZip;
}
```

And here is the output.

```
//  Names and zip codes:
//  ,bobby, 12345
//  ,tammy, 45677
//  ,cindy, 34512
```

Notice the beginning comma.  How do you get rid of it?

Comment: I think you can use substring (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp)

var string = ',bobby, 12345';
var removed = string.substring(1);

Comment: This is just a sample output.  The data is dependent on user input.

Comment: Can you use a conditional? `if(string.charAt(0)==","){...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of display the array string you can use `join('')`.

Code:

```
displayBox.innerHTML += "Names and zip codes: " + namePlusZip.join('');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/0n9ryc3h/

Comment: Its always something simple isn't it (:  Thanks, now I know how to handle this in the future.

Comment: the join() method by default takes ',' as the delimiter, so adding ',' as the parameter is not required here.

Answer (score 1):

If you declare your initial array like this:

```
var namePlusZip = [[]];
```

and after that push a new array there:

```
namePlusZip.push('one', 'two')
```

your array will look like this:

```
[[], ['one', 'two']]
```

If you paste in your console line:

```
[[], ['one', 'two']].join(',')
```

You will get this:

```
",one,two"
```

You don't have to declare array like [[]], just [] is enough

Also, I think your function is a bit wrong. Try this:

```
function displayData(){
    displayBox.innerHTML = "";

    var output = ''
    for (var i=0, l=namePlusZip.length; i<l; i++){
       if (namePlusZip[i] instanceof Array){
        console.log(namePlusZip[i]);
            var k = namePlusZip[i];
            t = k.join(',')
            console.log(t);
           output += t + "</br>"; 
       }
    }

    displayBox.innerHTML += "Names and zip codes: " + output;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, your way looks better.  With the way you wrote the function I can take out the delete      namePlusZip[0];